# File manager app does not show files on sd card on BQ E4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, files, filemanager, sd-card, bq

On my BQ E4.5 Ubuntu phone, the file manager app does not show files on the SD card.
I copied lost of mp3 to the SD card and I do not have any problem playing these files on the phone. When connecting the phone to the computer (Ubuntu 14.04) I can see the files, but when navigating to the SD card with the File manager  app on my phone, it says "0 files"! ( /media/phablet/6636-3164 (0 files)
(I double checked that the files are on the SD card and not on the phone itself).
Any ideas?

Comment: You could simply [link your SDCard to your home directory][1]. 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/651734/unlock-sd-card-ubuntu-touch/653606#653606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I figured it out.
It appeared to be rather easy. You should give your password to "unlock full access". Then all the files appear.